# vuejs routing with express server

Tags: vue.js

I've a node.js (express) application listening at localhost:4000/api

I'm working on a vuejs based client with router as follows,

```
const routes = [
{   
  path: '/customers',
  name: 'customers',
  component: Customers,
},  
{ 
  path: '/customers/:customer_id',
  name: 'customer_details',
  component: CustomerDetails,
},
]
```

I'm managing server path via vue.config.js file as,

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:4000'
         }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm also using state mgmt via store object/functionality as follows,

```
const BASE_URL = 'api/'
fetchCustomers(context) {
   const server_url = BASE_URL + '/customers'
   axios.get(server_url) 
   ...
}
```

This works fine, but

```
 fetchCustomer(context, id) {
   const server_url = BASE_URL + '/customers/' + id
   axios.get(server_url) 
   ...
}
```

This one fails with 404 error. When I checked on the server, I see that client is making call to,

```
/customers/api//customers/5c891995e5212d439459ff28
```

instead of

```
/api//customers/5c891995e5212d439459ff28
```

And at the client side I've a router-link as follows,

```
<router-link :to="{'name':'customer_details',
  params: {'customer_id': cid }}></router-link>
```

When I click on this link, I'm seeing following in the console,

GET http://localhost:8080/customers/api//customers/5c891995e5212d439459ff28 404 (Not Found)

If I remove vue.config.js and put BASE_URL with complete path as 'http://localhost:4000/api', then I don't see this error. Must be very small mistake but I'm not seeing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change your `BASE_URL` to `'/api'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked.